# Run a command shell in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, build, command, ioexception

I'm trying to execute a command shell in Jenkins, I'm working on Windows 7. In the console output I have this:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test
[test] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson6299483223982766034.sh
The system cannot find the file specified

FATAL: L'exécution de la commande a échoué.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:816)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Build step 'Exécuter un script shell' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea?

Comment: for some reason I don't think trying to run `sh` shells will work on windows. Perhaps you should try running `.bat` scripts instead since you're on windows?

Comment: Step by step instructions here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60326671/6648326

Answer (score 70):

For Windows slave, please use `Execute Windows batch command`.
For Unix-like slave like linux or Mac, `Execute shell` is the option.

[image: Execute Windows Command shell]

Comment: for me it's more simple to use shell command that's why i'm looking to execute a shell command on windows

Comment: Well, try providing the full path of 'sh' to jenkins.  Like this: `C:\Windows\sh  myfile.sh`

Comment: to be clear i'm trying to use curl command ,i can't do this with windows command and i'm not sure that can do that with shell command on jenkins, any idea?

Comment: @Medbraim it's not about what's "more simple" for you, it's about what your system supports. On Windows, there is no native `sh` executable, therefore you cannot use "Execute Shell" build step. Period. If you want to use "Execute Shell" build step, you need to install Cygwin (or similar) and make sure that `sh` executable is somewhere in the `PATH`

Comment: @Medbraim Installing an Cygwin may be too painful for you. If all you need is to run a cURL command in windows, then you only need to download and install cURL in windows and then make sure the cURL executable is somewhere in the PATH.

Comment: @mainframer - do you know where one can get step by step instructions to execute shell commands with cygwin ? I need this for a Jenkins tutorial. I would prefer to follow the tutorial exactly instead of using windows bat or such.

Comment: after changes of command execution from shell , to windows then it works for me

Answer (score 32):

As far as I know, Windows will not support shell scripts out of the box. You can install Cygwin or Git for Windows, go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System Shell and point it to the location of sh.exe file found in their installation. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

There is another option I've discovered. This one is better because it allowed me to use shell in pipeline scripts with simple `sh "something"`.

Add the folder to system PATH. Right click on Computer, click properties > advanced system settings > environmental variables, add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\` to your system Path property.

IMPORTANT note: for some reason I had to add it to the system wide Path, adding to user Path didn't work, even though Jenkins was running on this user.

An important note (thanks bugfixr!):

> This works. It should be noted that you will need to restart Jenkins in order for it to pick up the new PATH variable. I just went to my services and restated it from there.

Disclaimer: the names may differ slightly as I'm not using English Windows.

Comment: That is what I did. Installed Cygwin under C:\cygwin. Then Under Manage Jenkins > Configure > Shell (Shell Executable) I entered: c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe

Comment: Thank you. This was what ultimately worked for me. I hadn't run into the issue before, but I think it might be due to the fact that this time around I installed Jenkins in a separate drive from where git was installed.

Comment: This works. It should be noted that you will need to restart Jenkins in order for it to pick up the new PATH variable. I just went to my services and restated it from there.

Comment: Can I use WinSCP in place of cygwin or Git

Comment: You could try your luck with WinSCP.com file. I have not tried this approach.

Comment: Worked great for me. I tried at first to use the path from cygwin `c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe` which worked most of the time but not for the bash command `cut` which it did not recognize. So I tried instead to use what you recommended here `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` and it worked like a charm even with the bash command `cut`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**Error shows that script does not exists**

The file does not exists. check your full path

```
C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson6299483223982766034.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Moreover, to launch .sh scripts into windows, you need to have [CYGWIN](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed and well configured into your path

**Confirm that script exists.**

Into jenkins script, do the following to confirm that you do have the file

```
cd C:\Windows\TEMP\
ls -rtl
sh -xe hudson6299483223982766034.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

This is happens because Jenkins is not aware about the shell path.
In Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Shell, set the shell path as

- C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but not working for a mix Linux and Windows slave? This should be configurable at slave level.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties
Check the box 'Environment variables' and add the JAVA_HOME path = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"

*Don't write bin at the end

Answer (score 0):

I was running a job which ran a shell script in Jenkins on a Windows machine. The job was failing due to the error given below. I was able to fix the error thanks to clues in [Andrejz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43514090/6648326).

**Error :**

```
Started by user james
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\jamespc\.jenkins\workspace\myfolder\my-job
[my-job] $ sh -xe C:\Users\jamespc\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins933823447809390219.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:478)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Users\jamespc\.jenkins\workspace\myfolder\my-job"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Solution :**

**1 - Install Cygwin and note the directory where it gets installed.**

It was C:\cygwin64 in my case. The sh.exe which is needed to run shell scripts is in the "bin" sub-directory, i.e. C:\cygwin64\bin.

**2 - Tell Jenkins where sh.exe is located.**

Jenkins web console > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Under shell, set the "Shell executable" = C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe > Click apply & also click save.

That's all I did to make my job pass. I was running Jenkins from a war file and I did not need to restart it to make this work.