# Jenkins script execution in console output

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, mingw

When I try to execute the shell script **test.sh** in Jenkins by adding Execute Shell in Jenkins Build configuration I don't see the shell script output in the jenkins console. I just receive that script has been executed seccessfully , but I don't see the output. My script for example is simple just `

```
#!/bin/bash +x 
echo "hello"
```

and Jenkins console output is :

```
Started by user Andrej
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test
[test] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -xe C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6727659055076114908.sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

How can I configure the jenkins that I can see all the script output and if script have receive error I get unseccessfull build message?

Comment: Are you running this in a pipeline/Multi-Branch (`jenkinsfile`) job or a config.xml (`ui`) style job? Shell script execution differs depending on the job type.

Comment: @Wimateeka i have a folder of my project , i put scripts in this folder and try to execute script from jenkins by execute shell "./test.sh" and have no output in jenkins output console.

Comment: Have you already set up your windows version of Jenkins to run shell scripts? I noticed the path for your exe isn't for git or cygwin. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/43514090/8184374 . I use Jenkins on linux, so I haven't dealt with this before, but I will see if I can help.

Comment: @Wimateeka finally i make this! I just set path to *bin/bash.exe and set -xe instead of "git-bash.exe, and finally i get the output from bash, can you add answer which i can accept to close this question ? thanks a lot !:)

Comment: HI Андрей Ка, where did you set up the path( set path to *bin/bash.exe and set -xe instead of "git-bash.exe) on you Jenkins windows slave or windows server itself.Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set up your windows version of Jenkins to run shell scripts.

I noticed the path for your exe isn't for `git` or `cygwin`.

Check out [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43514090/8184374) for how to get windows to run shell commands in Jenkins.