# How to use GCloud in pipeline Windows

Tags: jenkins, gcloud

I have the following pipeline that is working correctly in linux system but I am looking the same for Windows System.

My Google Cloud is located in : C:\Software\gcloud\google-cloud-sdk\bin

And I have a global variable created in PATCH

[image]

How could I use gcloud in Jenkins under Windows System?

```
pipeline {
   agent any

stages {
    stage('Run gcloud') {

        steps {
            withEnv(['GCLOUD_PATH=/var/jenkins_home/google-cloud-sdk/bin']) {
                sh '$GCLOUD_PATH/gcloud --version'
            }


         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have this code in Windows

```
pipeline {
   agent any

stages {
    stage('Run gcloud') {

        steps {
            withEnv(['GCLOUD_PATH=C:\\Software\\gcloud\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin']) {
                sh '$GCLOUD_PATH\\ gcloud --version'
            }


         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the result when I launch jenkins is this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd picture shows that you are running a shell script on Windows? Unless you have "Windows Subsystem for Linux" or Cygwin, etc, I don't think that would work. To give proper credit where it's due, the solution might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374998/run-a-command-shell-in-jenkins/60326671#60326671)